# How to find rate of change across successive rows using time and data columns after grouping by a different column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame of the form:

**df**

```
ID_col time_in_hours data_col
  1        62.5         4
  1        40           3
  1        20           3
  2        30           1
  2        20           5
  3        50           6
```

What I want to be able to do is, find the rate of change of *data_col* by using the time_in_hours column. Specifically,

```
rate_of_change = (data_col[i+1] - data_col[i]) / abs(time_in_hours[ i +1] - time_in_hours[i])
```

Where *i* is a given row and the *rate_of_change* is calculated separately for different IDs

Effectively, I want a new DataFrame of the form:

**new_df**

```
ID_col time_in_hours data_col  rate_of_change
  1        62.5         4          NaN
  1        40           3         -0.044
  1        20           3          0
  2        30           1          NaN
  2        20           5          0.4
  3        50           6          NaN
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
s = df.groupby('ID_col').apply(lambda dft: dft['data_col'].diff() / dft['time_in_hours'].diff().abs())
s.index = s.index.droplevel()
s
```

returns

```
0         NaN
1   -0.044444
2    0.000000
3         NaN
4    0.400000
5         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks but this also gets rid of the 'ID's

Comment: @Melsauce you can set a column as normal: `df['rate_of_change'] = s`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pandas.diff`:

```
df.groupby('ID_col').apply(
   lambda x: x['data_col'].diff() / x['time_in_hours'].diff().abs())

ID_col   
1       0         NaN
        1   -0.044444
        2    0.000000
2       3         NaN
        4    0.400000
3       5         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually get around the `groupby` + `apply` given how your `DataFrame` is sorted. In this case, you can just check if the `ID_col` is the same as the shifted row.

So calculate the rate of change for everything, and then only assign the values back if they are within a group.

```
import numpy as np

mask = df.ID_col == df.ID_col.shift(1)
roc = (df.data_col - df.data_col.shift(1))/np.abs(df.time_in_hours - df.time_in_hours.shift(1))

df.loc[mask, 'rate_of_change'] = roc[mask]
```

## Output:

```
   ID_col  time_in_hours  data_col  rate_of_change
0       1           62.5         4             NaN
1       1           40.0         3       -0.044444
2       1           20.0         3        0.000000
3       2           30.0         1             NaN
4       2           20.0         5        0.400000
5       3           50.0         6             NaN
```